# Query Google Bigquery Through Python In Google App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to query a bigquery table and display results to a webpage using google apps engine(Biling enabled project). I am using python(3.4.3) for the development. Here is the code which i found and i an trying to work thru it, This is actually my main.py file:

```html
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID
PROJECT_ID = "725429XXXXXX"
# REPLACE WITH THE SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL FROM GOOGLE DEV CONSOLE
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '725429XXXXXX-si4unlakcnr3mXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

f = file('Key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
datasets = service.datasets()
response = datasets.list(projectId=PROJECT_ID).execute()

print('Dataset list:\n')
for dataset in response['datasets']:
  print("%s\n" % dataset['id'])


# SELECT data

query_data = {'query':'
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Sample.QCOMMREBATE];
'}
query_request = service.jobs()
query_response = query_request.query(projectId=PROJECT_ID, 
    body=query_data).execute()
pp.pprint(query_response)
```

However hard i try i am not getting the results on the local page or on the deployed page.

Can anyone tell me if i am doing something wrong anywhere.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Error after signing is : HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/725429946316/queries?alt=json returned "Encountered " "BY" "by "" at line 1, column 113.

Comment: Weird error, doesn't make much sense for the code you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from a py developer but the real issue was the SQL which i was trying to pass. The group by had no space in between.